# how to deliminate string with different and multiple deliminater

Tags: python

I have a string (python), that has the date, model, make, and the year  it is below:

```
string = "Mar 17 1997 H569, CAT: 2022"
```

I want to write a program that will ask the user to enter the string, and the program will automatically do something like:

```
date: data
model:data
make: data
year: data
```

The question, how can I deliminate,since I have space, comma, colon, etc. If I use characters then the problem will be not all makes and model have the same number of characters. What I am trying to do is to deliminate a string with more than once deliminater randomly mixed, in python?

Comment: You need to decide how you want to identify the fields.  For example, you could base it on field widths, with the first 11 characters always being the date, etc.  Or you could base it on white space, with the date always containing two internal spaces.  There is no single correct answer, since it depends on your data format, which only you know.  Once you decide *exactly* how you want it to behave, then you can ask a more specific question about how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a regex:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('(\w+ \d+ \d+) (\w+), (\w+): (\d+)')

string = "Mar 17 1997 H569, CAT: 2022"
regex.findall(string)
```

output: `[('Mar 17 1997', 'H569', 'CAT', '2022')]`

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input('date :') #"Mar 17 1997 H569, CAT: 2022"
mounth,day,dyear,model,make,year=string.split()
print(f'date:{day}/{mounth}/{year}')
print(f'model:{model.strip(",")}')
print(f'make:{make.strip(":")}')
print(f'year:{year}')
```